# How do I make my app look like a standard Android app?

Tags: java, android

I notice that most android apps have some sort of standard in that they all look similar.  Most of them have some sort of list of Text that are click-able.  It's somewhat hard to explain but they look really nice and I was wondering is there some sort of tool or api that allows me to change the look of an app to make it similar?  Or do I have to specifically specify the different fonts and different graphics?  Like this:

http://www.androidandme.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/tmobapp1.png

I am new to Android programming so sorry if this sounds like a dumb question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by reading up on the UI design guidelines provided by google:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

Answer (score 0):

They are simply using the same standard Android UI elements provided to them via the framework.  These views are readily available for you to use in Android.  You can see some [examples here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/tutorials/views/index.html).

In the case of your image example, they are using a [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html) and a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).